# Eigenvalues of a symbolic 28×28 Hessian matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have a little problem trying to calculate the eigenvalues of big symbolic (depending on $a$) Hessian matrices (28×28, 32×32 ...).

I think I've understand, by reading other posts, that *Mathematica* can not calculate the eigenvalues of such matrices since, I don't know why, it can not find the roots of the characteristic polynomial.

My goal is to find the lowest eigenvalue to see at which $a$ it vanishes.
How could I do that since I don't have any idea at which $a$ it happens ?
Thanks you

Comment: is it possible to provide the smallest available instance of the problem?

Comment: If the goal is to find when an eigenvalue vanishes, why don't you look at the determinant instead?

Comment: Well actually that a good solution, i'm pretty dumb since if H is my matrix and a_1,a_2,...,a_q are its eigenvalues Det[H]=a_1*...*a_q right ?

Comment: Oh no i remember now, I already tried to calculate the Det,but it mathematica gives me something like :                               (1/((3.33262*10^-261 - 4.58187*10^-262a)^5)) *5.760357996978126*10^1833 a^7* (0.*10^-3127 + 0.*10^-3127 a + 
   0.*10^-3128 a^2 + 0.*10^-3128 a^3 + 0.*10^-3129 a^4 + 
   0.*10^-3129 a^5 + 0.*10^-3130 a^6 + 0.*10^-3131 a^7 + 
   0.*10^-3132 a^8 + 0.*10^-3134 a^9 + 0.*10^-3135 a^10 + 
   0.*10^-3137 a^11 + 0.*10^-3139 a^12)

Comment: so as you can see it never vanishes (which is false)

Comment: Since most of your constants in your Det are 0.* 10^-3131 or smaller it looks like you have some decimal numbers in your matrix which don't have more than 3130 good known digits after the decimal point. Try redoing your Det with say 6260 digits of precision for every constant and see what you get. Otherwise your N[det]==0. (to one digit of precision)

Comment: how can i chose the number of digit is use ?

Comment: You could use `Chop`. But anyway, as already said, hard to help without some code. (yes, I know that's an old post)